# File use UTF-8 encoding by could not read in ios

Tags: ios

You should download the file first:
[test file link](http://files.cnblogs.com/shappy1978/Archive.zip)
While I got data from server,I found that sometimes may get a nil response,so I save the data into a text file(buffer.txt contains in zip fiel),and I do the follow test(put the tow file to your document directory first,the file may a little big and contains many chinese,but that's not the problem):

```
NSError *error=nil;
NSString *fPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
fPath = [fPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"buffer.txt"];
s = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if(error) 
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
else
    NSLog(@"%@",s);
```

When you read buffer.txt,it raise an error:The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 261.),error code 261 means encodeing incorrect,but I sure the file is UTF-8.Buffer2.txt can read successfully.
Then I open the buffer.txt in windows by notepad.exe and resave to buffer2.txt,and try to read by the code upper,word reads correct!
Now I knows buffer.txt really contains  some word is not UTF-8,it should be an emoji character "/ue346",read the buffer.txt at 0x4cbb:,you will get:

ED A0 BC ED BD 8A

it's not "/ue346",right?"/ue346" trans to UTF-8 is:

F0 9F 8D 8A

but it looks like the same emoji character:an orange,I don't know why UTF-8 have tow same "orange" and why the server change one "orange" to another "orange",that not the point!

The question is my android client can receive the data correctly,and the nopate.exe can correct the error charactor after resave.How could they do that,how to read the buffer.txt just like they do in ios.

sorry,i have modified the attachment link,you can down it again.

Comment: Your link is for registered user only, so I could not download your file.

Comment: I'm confused. You say "I sure the file is UTF-8" but then "I knows buffer.txt really contains some word is not UTF-8". To me, that says that the file is *not* UTF-8, and the error is correct. It doesn't matter if other systems have some way of interpreting the bad data.

Comment: It is UTF-8 encoding,for the server did set UTF-8 encoding,if u use TextEdit in mac to open it,it do cannot recognize the non english character(chinese),that means TextEdit can not recognize the encoding,bug at least it has been open,not empty!And in ios,that will be empty.

Comment: Second,the Android client can do open such file!It fixed the bad character,how could I make my boss realize that android can do things than ios can't do!I'm sure he will kid my back top and shout:go!Do as Android did!
Third,in windows notpad.exe can also open buffer.txt,resave to another can fix the wrong character,how did it do that?

Comment: I have got the solution,nopad and android did not correct the "error" character,infact there is no error."ED A0 BC ED BD 8A" is a 4 byte unicode(it is UTF-8 encodding,if translate to unicode,it is a 4 byte unicode,not a normal 2 byte unicode).Maybe the Mac and ios cannot regconize this charactor and raise error.And even worse,it will return nil,that's really bad user experience.

Comment: translate your self into unicode and than read to a NSString.

Comment: See this for help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995519/how-to-use-stringwithcontentsofurlencodingerror/11708840#11708840