# Too many arguments to method call expected 1 have 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, arguments, nsurl

Here is my code.

```
NSString *target = @"http://www.google.com/";
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"%@", target] encoding: -2147481280 error: nil];
```

My code gives me the error above

```
Too many arguments to method call expected 1 have 2
```

Somebody help me..

[image: Screenshot for error]

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995519/how-to-use-stringwithcontentsofurlencodingerror

Comment: [NSURL URLWithString:@"%@", target] -> URLWithString take a NSString as parameter, not a formatedString. The solution is replace by [NSURL URLWithString:target].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with the following code snippet:

```
[NSURL URLWithString:@"%@", target]
```

You don't need to specify the type specifier there.

You need to change your code like:

```
NSString *target = @"http://www.google.com/";
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:target] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error: nil];
```

Comment: @trojanfoe: I Just fixed that, I just copied the code from question and only changed the issue causing part :)

Answer (score 0):

Choose one of these.

```
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", target]] encoding: -2147481280 error: nil];
```

or

```
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:target] encoding: -2147481280 error: nil];
```

Comment: The first form includes a useless `stringWithFormat:`, so there is really only one choice.

Comment: @trojanfoe I assumed that he might modified the URL with NSStringWithFormat. That's why I added.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like that as well just one line of code:-

```
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error: nil];
```