# JSON parsing with £ symbol returning null

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to parse a JSON script from my server which contains a £ (pound) however this is returning null. I had problems before so temporarily just switched to using dollars or euro sign but I need to be able to parse the pound sign. However I am unsure as to how to rectify this issue. I created a test project and temporarily just using String with contents method, all the other jsons work fine, but the one with the pound sign in it returns null.

```
NSString *get5 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url5 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

I tried the other encoding NSUTF encoding but they dont seem to work either. Some return null, some return chinese characters, so they are not much good.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Edit:

Used the NSError object and got this message back

> "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 261.)"
>   UserInfo=0x68294b0
>   {NSURL=http://myserver.com/test.jsp,
>   NSStringEncoding=4}

Comment: i did not see the error code you posted( Cocoa 261)!I corrected the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocoa Error 261 is an encoding error. The service returning the JSON obviously isn't returning it with an UTF-8 encoding. Either make the service returns UTF-8 if you can, or find out which encoding it is returning and use that.

See this question for more info:

[Encoding issue: Cocoa Error 261?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931113/encoding-issue-cocoa-error-261)

Comment: Cheers for information. I went through the other encoding techniques and found one that worked!!

Answer (score 1):

Can you check that the json is not encoded in 1) CRLF (windows)encoding 2) Western etc. 
Make sure the encoding is UTF-8