# iOS Read a Stream but returns null

Tags: ios, json, file-read

Ok boys and girls, this is my prob :

I'd like to read a JSON stream in my iOS app, but when i tried, it returns

```
2013-04-12 02:35:01.479 Test[81414:303] (null)
```

but my file exist and is absolutely not empty !! You can find it here http://api.kalokod.com/cce/mainfeed.json

And my script to read it is :

```
NSError *error;

    NSURL *file = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.kalokod.com/cce/mainfeed.json"];


    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:file
                                                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                   error:&error];

    NSLog(@"%@", string);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code, and received a `Cocoa Error 261`. This means that the JSON you are trying to load isnt encoded with UTF-8, so using `NSUTF8StringEncoding` wont work. Try this

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:file
                                            encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                               error:&error];
```

Comment: You have to put `if (err) { NSLog(@"%@", err); }` so if there is an error, it logs what the problem was

Comment: Okay thanks, btw, NSJSONSerialization doesn't work with this file (due to encoding type ? Maybe...) Do you know any method to parse this JSON anyway ? This is my method :
`- (NSDictionary *)CCEJSONParser:(NSString *)JSONFile {
    
    NSURLRequest *JSONRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:JSONFile]];
    
    NSData *jsonData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:JSONRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    
NSError *error = Nil;
    
 NSDictionary *JSONParser = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
    
return JSONParser;
}`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931113/encoding-issue-cocoa-error-261) might be your problem -- that there are non-UTF8 characters in your JSON string.

Log your `NSError *error` to see if you get a Cocoa error 261.